# MinGW undefined reference to `WsaIoctl'

Tags: c++, mingw32

I'm using MinGW on Win 7. I'm triyng to compile C++ code using WsaIoctl. However, I got the error

*undefined reference to `WsaIoctl'*

I use -lwldap32 -lws2_32 -lwsock32 -lmswsock flags.

Thanks for advice,
Slava

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no win32 function called WsaIoctl. You need [WSAIoctl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms741621%28VS.85%29.aspx)

Comment: @Slava it would help if you copy pasted the command you run and copy paste the error message too.

Comment: $ gcc -std=gnu99  -O3   -o minerd.exe minerd-cpu-miner.o minerd-util.o minerd-s
ha2.o minerd-sha2-arm.o minerd-sha2-x86.o minerd-sha2-x64.o minerd-scrypt.o min
erd-scrypt-arm.o minerd-scrypt-x86.o minerd-scrypt-x64.o -L/usr/local/lib -lcur
l -lwldap32 -lws2_32 compat/jansson/libjansson.a  -lws2_32 -lpthread -lwsock32
-lmswsock
minerd-util.o:util.c:(.text+0x10b): undefined reference to `WSAIoctl'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: Also I can say I got warning during compilation:

Comment: Also I can say I got warning during compilation:'util.c:322:5: warning: implicit declaration of function 'WSAIoctl' [-Wimplicit-f
unction-declaration]'
     if (WSAIoctl(fd, /*sio_keepalive_vals*/ 0, &alive, sizeof(alive),
     ^   Also, I want to add, I use make first and gcc after with -pthread option, because makefile doesn't content this flag for some reasons and I don't know how to add it there. However, if I comment code with WSAIoctl I get exe right.

Comment: Then you're might have included winsock.h instead of winsock2.h, or somwhere you got winsock.h included before winsock2.h

Comment: But as I understand it is issue of linking, not compiling. Can this be related?

Comment: I did as you stated. Commented winsock2.h. Same result :(

Comment: @Slave it is probably the cause of your problems, your compiler doesn't see the prototype for WSAIoctl, and it thus won't see the DLL export attributes on that function which will cause it to fail when linking. You're *not* supposed to comment out winsock2.h, I didn't say that. You have some kind of error in your setup or source code that causes the compiler to not see the declaration of WSAIoctl (which should be in winsock2.h - but if you also include winsock.h, possibly indirectly via stdafx.h or afxsock.h etc. there will be issues too.) - I can't debug that for you.

Comment: My project contents curl and it requires winsock.h. So I can't exclude it from the project completely. But WSAIoctl requires winsock2.h and these two files are conflicting as you say. Where are then compromise?

Comment: Problem was solved. It was related with mstcpip.h that I commented. So when I included it in project right, mentioned warning disappeared. Thanks.